# Servicing mechanical selector switches / rotary encoders

Tags: switches, repair, mechanical

After 15 years of use, one of my Alps mechanical selector switches (metal contact spring dragging across metal tracks) had developed oxidised/dirty contacts.

After some cleaning with alcohol and Kontakt 60 the contacts are once more shiny and the switch is ready to be reassembled. - Just one last issue: should the contact spring which drags across the contact tracks be lubricated or protected against moisture?

If yes, using what? Silicone oil/grease, WD 40, watchmaker's oil? Or is keeping everything dry and clean best?

Comment: Do you have any pictures? For all things in contact (electrical and mechanical) with the rotating assembly, what materials are they made of?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about corrosion, you could use some form of [bulb grease](http://www.bobistheoilguy.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=2957925) in a very small quantity.

Personally, I would only apply the grease if the device operates in an environment with high humidity or big temperature changes AND is exposed to ambient air.

Answer (score 1):

When I used to maintain the old Strowger telephone system, we applied a light oil to the contacts of the two-motion selectors and uniselectors. I assume the reason was to reduce wear on the contact banks.